# Is ambiguous the same as incomplete?

Tags: ambiguity

I am aware that when something (a statement, sentence, etc.) is ambiguous it leads to uncertainty due to more than one interpretation; but does ambiguous imply incomplete? Put another way, can something be incomplete yet unambiguous? Any examples would help.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: How is this an English language usage question? Sounds more like philosophy to me.

Comment: Apologies if my question is not suitable. I am very fussy and trying to understand what (if any) difference there is; I often see statements such as "... ambiguous and incomplete...". I want to understand to help me use just one correct word to describe issues when reviewing technical documents.

Comment: You seem to be a native speaker so the question seems odd to me. I think you mean: is it redundant?

Comment: What do you mean by *complete*?  It seems that every statement - every statement that is not the utterance of the entire universe - could be called "incomplete."  That is, every statement leaves out most information. An unambiguous statement contains enough information that the statement can be understood exactly as the speaker intended.  That is probably not how I would define *complete*.

Comment: You may want to rephrase this as a single-word-request with an example sentence that matches your situation.

Comment: If I use the character `O` it's often ambiguous (depending on font) as to whether it means the letter "oh" or the numeral "zero".  It is not "incomplete", however, since, in the proper context, it's meaning can be readily determined.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. They have all helped me to understand my own question in more detail which is related to technical documentation, mostly requirements definitions. I will need to think of specific examples of all possibilities (two values, ambiguity and completeness, result in four possibilities).

Comment: Continued... (I accidently submitted the comment before finishing). A generic example would be "The user can download the log file up to 5 times.". This is certainly ambiguous, does it mean they can download 4 times and the 5th attempt will fail, or 5 times and the 6th attempt will fail? I could change it to say ... up to and including 5 times to remove ambiguity. Thank you all again.

Comment: Whenever a sentence is ambiguous, it can be said that it is incomplete *insofar as* it misses something that would make it unambiguous. It is probably this connection between the two concepts that prompted the question. A sentence that is incomplete in that way may, however, at the same time, be complete along many other dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ambiguous* and *incomplete* are two distinct concepts. You can check the definitions in any reputable dictionary, but here is some illumination:

**Statements can be ambiguous without being incomplete:**

> “Welcome, O life! I go to encounter for the millionth time the reality of experience and to forge in the smithy of my soul the uncreated conscience of my race.” —James Joyce, *A Portrait of the Artist as a Young Man*

Here the ambiguity lies in the verb *to forge*, which splits along two lines: forging as a constructive process ("a blacksmith forges weapons") and a duplicitous one ("a thief may forge your signature on a check", "this painting is a forgery"). This sort of ironic wordplay was bread and butter to Joyce. But the statement in the novel is certainly complete.

**Statements can be incomplete without being ambiguous:**

> A: Can I borrow a dollar?
>   B: I don't have any money.

B may have money, just none to lend to A. The statement is incomplete, but there is no ambiguity, since for the purposes of the conversation *there is no money* and a further explanation is not required.

That said,

**A statement may be ambiguous *because* it is incomplete**:

> *I like the way you move* [my furniture].

Leaving out the furniture leaves the statement open to multiple interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of an ambiguous yet complete sentence: *I saw a man on a hill with a telescope.*

This could mean the following:

- There’s a man on a hill, and I’m
  watching him with my telescope.
- There’s a man on a hill, who I’m
  seeing, and he has a telescope.
- There’s a man, and he’s on a hill
  that also has a telescope on it.
- I’m on a hill, and I saw a man using
  a telescope.
- There’s a man on a hill, and I’m seeing him with a
  telescope.

Defining 'incomplete' as *not having all the necessary or appropriate parts.* or *not full or finished* (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incomplete), my example sentence wouldn't fall into that category.

Put simply, they're two completely different categories.